# PHP display values of specific keys from one array based on values from another array

Tags: php, arrays, listings

For the past week, I've been working on a PHP page to display an online internal stock of devices

The issue I'm facing and where I got stuck is the following:

I have 2 arrays, as follow:

- the first one is created using the `explode()` function on a string;
- the second one is created using a `foreach()` on a `$query->result_array()` received from MySQL query interrogation

When I output both arrays, the look like this:

```
// 1st array

Array (
    [0] => NAME
    [1] => TAG
    [2] => SERVICE
    [3] => TYPE
    [4] => COMMENT
    [5] => LOCATION
    )

// 2nd array

Array (
    [ID] => 3
    [ID_CAT] => 10
    [NAME] => test
    [TAG] => 123456789
    [SERVICE] => PAID
    [TYPE] => SIM
    [COMMENT] => Needs activation
    [LOCATION] => A city
    [STATUS] => Available
)
```

The arrays are not the same length:

- 1st has the length 6
- 2nd has the length 9

My question is: **How can I show the values of 2nd array, based on the match made on the 1st array ?**

Actually the match is something like this: `if (1st array value == 2nd array key) { output }`

I've tried a `foreach()` and a `for()` loop, but it will only show me only 1 value (`$i` always is 0)

Here's the double `foreach()` loops I tried:

```
foreach($1st_array as $key1st => $value1st) {
    foreach($2nd_array as $values2nd) {
       if (strcmp($key1st , $values2nd) == 0) { print '<td>'.$value1st.'</td>'; }
    }
}
```

... and here is the `foreach()` and `for()` loops I've tried:

```
foreach($1st_array as $key1st => $value1st) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($2nd_array); $i++) {
      if ($key1st == $2nd_array[$i]) {
        print '<td id="'.$i.'">'.$value1st.'</td>';
      }
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work ?

This is giving me a headache :(

All answers will be deeply appreciated!

My best regards,
Michael

**LATER EDIT:**

@**Nevermind**: The output I want from the 2 arrays would be like this:

- Name: 'test'
- Tag: '123456789'
- Service: 'PAID'
- Type: 'SIM'
- Comment: 'Needs activation'
- Location: 'A city'

@**Don't Panic**: Correct, "STATUS" was a typo! Sorry about that

Comment: what's expected output with examples of your array1 & 2?

Comment: `foreach($arr1 as $val) if (isset($arr2[$val])) echo $arr2[$val];`

Comment: Are you putting commas in the array? Rather, can you? that's hard to look at.

Comment: I'm not sure about your expected output; status is not one of the values in the first array. Is it a typo or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I've posted a solution which might work. I'm guessing you didn't really need the first array?

Comment: You fixed formatting, thanks. Either way, you are testing the key from the first array to the value of the second array, is that what you want to do? That's why you are getting 1 match... OK, from your output, no. You need to shift your checks to test the 1st array value to the 2nd array key. Or you can try something posted in the answers.

Comment: Please manually write a line what result you want when the comparison is made

Comment: you can use `array_key_exists(key, $arr)` to check if a particular index exists in `$arr` or not

Comment: @Mani: Please check the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802492/ for more details and what do I expect!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isset()` with the value of the 1st array as the key of the 2nd array -

```
foreach($1st_array as $key){
    if(isset($2nd_array[$key])){
        echo $key . ": " . $2nd_array[$key]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you would like to merge the two arrays, mapping the values of the first array to the keys of the second.

Try the following.

```
<?php 

$array1 = Array (
     'NAME',
     'TAG',
     'SERVICE',
     'TYPE',
    'COMMENT',
    'LOCATION'
    );

 $array2 = $favorite_foods = Array (
    'ID'=> 3,
    'ID_CAT' => 10,
    'NAME' => 'test',
    'TAG'=> 123456789,
    'SERVICE' => 'PAID',
    'TYPE' => 'SIM',
    'COMMENT' => 'Needs activation',
    'LOCATION' => 'A city',
    'STATUS' => 'Available'
);



foreach ($array2 as $key => $value):
//search the value in array, which is the 
//key of the array2.
$position = array_search($key, $array1);

    if ($position !== false):
            echo "  $key<br/>";
    else:

        echo "-NO MATCH-<br/>";

    endif;

endforeach;


--Output--

-NO MATCH-
-NO MATCH-
NAME
TAG
SERVICE
TYPE
COMMENT
LOCATION
-NO MATCH-
```