# PHP displays only the first value in a for() loop insinde another foreach() loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have small issue with a for() loop that displays values inside another foreach() loop in a dynamic way.

A small background of the code:

1. The output table is created dynamically based on the values obtain from one mysql query SELECT (which is the 1st select) from 1 column (that has name "coloane") in a table called "categories";
2. The values stored in the column "coloane" are actually the name of some columns from another table called "articles"
3. The first mysql select is to obtain the values from the column "coloane" so I can create the second.
   After the second table returns rows (num_rows() > 0) I start to create the table.
4. The table has 2 static columns that are always present, and the rest of the columns are added dynamically based on different criteria.

The plot:

- I explode the values obtained from the first select - from the column "coloane" - to make the [th]'s for the table header;
- this explode I store it under the variable "$rows_th";
- to make the [th]'s for the table header, i use a foreach() loop (and here I also remove any underscores);
- after that I proceed to create the [tbody] and the [td]'s using another foreach(), only that this foreach is done for the values of the second select;
- inside this foreach() I create another loop, using the for() function on the variable "$rows_th" so the table has the same length;
- here the values are combined like this:

  ```
   '<td id="'.$i.'">'.$values_td[$rows_th[$i]].'</td>';
  ```

The main issue is that, using the format listed above, **it will only display the first value**!

When I tried to verify the "$values_td[$rows_th[$i]]" using the is_string() function, I discovered that the first value is a string, and after that, every other value is not a string...

The test performed:

```
     if (is_string($values_td[$rows_th[$i]]))
       print '<td id="'.$i.'">Value found!!!</td>';
     } else {
       print '<td id="'.$i.'">No luck...</td>';
     }
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong ?

I know I'm missing something, but I just can't seem to figure it out :-/

The entire code is listed here: http://pastebin.com/4MFifh92

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM results_query_header_by_cat WHERE `id` = 3;
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM results_query_content_by_cat WHERE `id_category` = 3;
```

Then with the results:

```
echo '[thead]';
foreach ( $results as $result ){
    foreach( $result['coloane'] as $header ){
        echo '[th]'.$header.'[/th]';
    }
} 
echo '[/thead][tbody]';
foreach ( $records as $record ){
    echo '[tr][td]' . 
     $result['producator'] . '[/td][td]' .
     $result['model'] . '[/td][td]' .
     $result['imei'] . '[/td][td]' .
     $result['locatie'] . '[/td][/tr]';
}
echo '[/tbody]';
```

Is that what you're looking for?

e: I haven't tried this but I'd imagine it's something like that. Just:

- get the headers by category ID
- get the records by category ID.
- Echo the first result set as headers with a loop,
- echo the second result set as table rows with columns in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, with the help from a friend, I finally found what was going wrong.

The variable turns from string to number because in the table called "categories", the column named "coloane" has the values inside devided by a "," (comma) and a " " (space), like so

```
  ------------------------------------------
  | coloane                                |
  ------------------------------------------
  make, model, location, comments, status
  ------------------------------------------
```

To fix this, I found out that I can try to do a [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.str-replace.php) in a simple foreach() loop :)

Something like this:

```
 $i=0;
 foreach($rows_th as $values_th) {
        $i++;
        $cols_td = str_replace(' ', '', $values_th);
        $actual_value = $values_td->$cols_td;
        print '<td id="'.$i.'">'.$actual_value.'</td>';
 }
```

And this did the trick :)

Hope this will help others that came across with issues similar to this :)

Best regards,
Mike